# How I can restrict Ember.logger to warn and error in production build?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In Ember production build, I want to enable only "Ember.Logger.warn" & "Ember.Logger.error" and rest of the Ember logger should be disabled.

i.e
Non production  - set to "debug” all logs should be displayed (any Ember.Logger….)
Prod  - set to “warn” display only warn & errors ( Ember.Logger.warn & Ember.Logger.error)

It will be helpful, if you guys give a solution.

Comment: Guys, If anyone knows, it will be helpful for me

Comment: Got an answer, refer the link https://github.com/jkarsrud/ember-cli-defeatureify

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer for that.

We can achieve this by using an add-on, refer the link https://github.com/jkarsrud/ember-cli-defeatureify, which helped me to do it.